# After Effects - Double View in Composition Tab

Tags: after-effects

I was working on my main composition (Comp 1) and it suddenly became a double-sided view (one at the top and one at the bottom). I don't know how can I fix it, but it's related to **Composition Mini-Flowchart**. (Working in After Effects 2020)

[image]

**How do I fix that and have a single comp view?**

Answer (score 0):

That was very simple, I should **change this to "1 View"**:

[image]